# How to rename table from Azure mobile service?

Tags: azure, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, azure-mobile-services

I am following [this](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-dotnet/) article. In step # 4 TodoItem table is created in mobile service. Now when I manage the database of that mobile service, I am getting the rename feature. (manage database is the screen which opens as silverlight app). So I want to know how can I rename TodoItem table to any other name. I created as TodoItem. Mobile service and database both is having that name I can rename in manage database but how can I rename from mobile service page.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to delete the old table in the portal (which no longer points to a table in SQL, because you renamed it - IT'S IMPORTANT TO DO THIS FIRST OR YOU'LL DELETE YOUR DATA!). Then create a new table in the Portal with the same name as the new table - that should automatically hook up to the existing table.

Comment: You mean if my table has some data and I have changed its name in portal and then if I delete table name from mobile service then I will lose the data. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes along later still looking for the answer to this...

Based on ConfusedNoob's reply I verified these steps:

- On Windows Azure management site (manage.windowsazure.com), go to SQL DB section
- Select your DB and click "Manage". Sign in to the DB management portal.
- Go to Administration and click "Design" for your DB
- Select "Edit" for the table you want to rename
- Change the table name to the new name, click Save
- Go back to Azure management. View your Mobile Services Data.
- Highlight your table that you want to rename and delete it. (Since you renamed the underlying DB table, the Mobile Services table is no longer associated with the actual table).
- Create a Mobile Services table with the new table name. Your data should show up in there. Do not create the table with the new name first because it will create a new empty table instead of pointing to the existing table.